# How do I get an NFT collection holders?

Tags: nft, collection, snapshot

Here's what I have tried, and it seems to be buggy.

Using SolScan.io I found the collection, then went to Holders, and clicked "next" to get the next 10.

I realized this data is wrong, as in, the total count is off and also the data returned contains duplicates.

I used the API that generates this data, and get the wrong info, even when setting the offset and limits to 50 at a time.

`https://pro-api.solscan.io/v1.0/public/nft/collection/stats?collectionId=xyz&filter=holders&offset=0&limit=50`

Is there a way to get this "holder snapshot"? Tools and other websites I have found online don't seem to be working (Jan 2023).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to do this would be to generate the mint list of the collection, several tools like Famous Fox Snapshot can help (https://famousfoxes.com/snapshot). Once you have the list of tokens in the collection, you can query the RPC directly for the largest accounts (https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettokenlargestaccounts) and since it's an NFT only one will have a positive balance. Repeat this for every token in the mint list.

Comment: https://famousfoxes.com/snapshot works well and fast, in Jan 2023 it looks to me as the only one that does.

Answer (score 0):

Found your collection ID and search it on Solscan, easily you can go to holders tab.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, as per my question, this is buggy. the Holders tab returns a list of duplicate wallet addresses and I confirmed it is missing some wallets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaboss to take snapshot of your holders.